# Como ordenar por vários campos com Ionic e/ou AngularJS de um JSON?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic, angularjs-services

Estou tentando ordenar campos dinamicamente pelo Ionic e o AngularJs. Comecei usando o plugin [Modal Select](https://github.com/inmagik/ionic-modal-select), com o botão assim:

```
<button class="button button-stable button-block icon-left ion-android-restaurant" modal-select="" ng-model="someModel" options="selectableNames" option-property="role" modal-title="Ordenar por..." header-footer-class="bar-assertive">Ordenar
    <div class="option">
        <h2>{{option.name}}</h2>
    </div>
</button>
```

E o `controller` assim:

```
// ORDENA POR...
$scope.selectableNames = [
    {
        name: "Por preço: Do Menor para o Maior",
        role: "+cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto"
    },
    {
        name: "Por preço: Do Maior para o Menor",
        role: "-cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto"
    },
    {
        name: "Por Maior Desconto (%)",
        role: "-cadastra_oferta_desconto"
    },
    {
        name: "Menor Prazo de Entrega",
        role: "+fornecedor_configura_frete_prazo_entrega_min"
    },
    {
        name: "Oferta em Ordem Alfabética",
        role: "+cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao"
    },
    //...
];
```

Colocando meu `filter` na *view* desta forma:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="item in ofertass | filter:q | orderBy:someModel | unique: 'cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta'" ng-init="$last ? fireEvent() : null" href="#/nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}">
```

Ordena até bem, mas os campos de preços que são:

```
{
    name: "Por preço: Do Menor para o Maior",
    role: "+cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto"
},
{
    name: "Por preço: Do Maior para o Menor",
    role: "-cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto"
},
// ...
```

Quanto tem centavo, ele não ordena direito. O que é curioso, pois o campo "desconto" que tem o mesmo formato que os campos valores ele ordena bem.

```
{
    name: "Por Maior Desconto (%)",
    role: "-cadastra_oferta_desconto"
},
```

Já tentei colocar `| currency` no "role" mas não aceita. Então quero fazer esta ordenação de forma diferente, mas não sei como e não encontrei nada na Internet. Teria que ser uma modal para filtrar estes campos. O meu `JSON` pode [ser acessado aqui](http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_oferta_api.php?json=promocao).

Como posso criar uma ordenação com diversos campos e tipos utilizando "Modal" e este meu `JSON`. Não precisando, necessariamente, utilizar este plugin mencionado no inicio desta questão.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você pode disponibilizar um Codepen com o seu código? Aqui tem um modelo do Modal Select para você usar: http://codepen.io/bianchimro/pen/epYYQO?editors=101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com Angular, primeiramente, recomendo que NÃO utilize a ordenação (ou qualquer outro tipo de filtro) através do `filter`, especialmente dentro de um `ngRepeat`, o impacto em performance é realmente grande quando se trabalha com listas extensas.

Quanto ao problema propriamente dito, não sei como você está utilizando mais de um campo, mas o correto é efetuar a declaração através de uma array, por exemplo:

```
orderBy: ['nome', '-idade', 'ativo']

// No seu exemplo
ng-repeat="item in ofertass | orderBy:['cadastra_oferta_desconto', 'currency']
```

> Nota: Para declaração em ordem crescente, não há necessidade da utilização de `+`, apenas o nome do campo.

Então, unificando as duas soluções que acabei de passar, o ideal seria ordenar a lista utilizando o filtro `$filter`, dentro do seu `controller` (ou `service`), recomendo que você utilize um código nesse estilo:

```
// HTML
<select ng-model="campoOrdena" ng-change="ordenarLista()">
    <option value="nome">Nome</option>
    <option value="-valor">Valor</option>
</select>

<div class="card" ng-repeat="item in ofertas">

// AngularJs
$scope.ofertas = [...]; //Sua array com os objetos a serem ordenados

$scope.ordenarLista = function() {
    // Explicando: $filter('orderBy')( "lista a ser ordenada", "campos para ordenar");
    // Ex.: $filter('orderBy')( $scope.ofertas, ['nome', 'valor', '-idade']);

    $scope.ofertas = $filter('orderBy')($scope.ofertas, $campoOrdena); // Lista com a nova ordem
}
```

Outro ponto que notei agora, para que você possa ordenar corretamente com valores (sejam eles monetários ou apenas numéricos), é importante que o campo seja do tipo `int`, caso contrário ele não terá consistência nos resultados, o que pode ser o seu caso, visto que o seu `JSON` está retornando o campo desconto como `string`.

Essa é a ideia geral, com isso acho que você terá o conhecimento para adaptar o seu código para utilizar a solução proposta. Se ainda tiver dúvidas, deixe um comentário que tentarei ajudar!

Comment: Obrigado @CelsomTrindade. Funcionou perfeito. Valeu!